# How to apply for Paypal AppID & Download Invoice Details (with PHP examples)

Tags: php, paypal-rest-sdk, php-curl

I know there’s lots of posts on this subject but I have read dozens and in every one that contains a link, I get a 404 error when I follow it to PP website and PP website help is very sparse and half their own links product 404 errors also.

I have been able to get the TransactionSearch API function call working using a CURL call as it doesn’t require an AppID but try as I might, I cant find a way to apply for this ID other than using the Sandbox one they provide with sandbox accounts.

All I want to do it download the transaction details from purchases we make on PayPal.  I can get the transaction summary, but this is missing the InvoiceID but is a start.  The PHP I downloaded in the Angell Eye project mostly need this AppID to work and while Sandbox is fine, I can’t use it to test with because I can’t get the minimal required details needed for a transaction search which is either the Invoice ID or the merchant account email.  I have all this in my live account data and can’t access this without the AppID.

However, all the good help I find is 10 years out of data and even the Angel Eye project is full of PHP warnings about deprecated functions and libraries.

Can someone please help me to find how to download the details, preferably in a PDF or printable format that is equivalent to logging into my PP account and previewing my purchase invoices.   I want to integrate this into my business system website so staff don’t need to log into my PP account to retrieve this information when they make a purchase which they need to do so they can add the invoice to our expenses database when they purchase parts for a job.

At the moment, I have got an API call that I run to download the transaction summary and add this to a MySQL database.  What I need to get it the invoice ID and the rest of the invoice details by starting with the transaction ID.  If I can do this without getting an AppID, that’s even better as I don’t need to integrate any payments or anything, I just want to download details of transactions that have been completed elsewhere.

Comment: Its all documented on the PayPal developer site. SO is not a tutorial site, we help each other with coding issues.

Answer (score 0):

App IDs are used by the Adaptive Payments API, which was deprecated in December of 2017. This API can no longer be used.

Current APIs authenticate with a REST APP's clientid and secret only.

There is an v2/invoicing API, which is used to manage invoices, but it is not clear whether that is what you are asking about. If what you need are details for a specific transaction use the v2/payments API to get details.

In general the payments get details and Transaction Search APIs should not be used; a checkout integrated with v2/checkout/orders for example already returns all transaction information in the capture API response. Store the information in your own database.

Comment: Thanks for that, it explains why I cant find any way to get the illusive APP ID.   What I want is to download details of paypal transactions from things i have bought on paypal for my business.  I want enough detail to be able to reconstruct a sudo tax invoice from those details instead of using the login to the website the going to view transactions, print preview then save as PDF.  The idea is that I can download these invoices or the details for them so staff do not need to log into my PP account and save the PDF versikon of the invocie.   I have a Client ID & Secret, how do i proceed

Comment: Log in to www.paypal.com and click on Activity, All reports, Activity download

Comment: #Preston PHX, thanks but I am looking for a way to acheive this using a PayPal API call so my system can retreive these details for my staff without me needing to give my staff the login and 2fa device required to access my paypal account.   I know how to download these from my account, but i need to integrate this into my payment and business management software.

Comment: Activity reports are still the best way. Create user(s) with appropriate permissions, https://www.paypal.com/us/cshelp/article/how-do-i-manage-users-on-my-business-account-help274